# How to announce data entered in a survey might be distributed under the ODbL?

Tags: licensing

I'm making a survey using Google Forms. I *plan* (if I can find time) to distribute the dataset (or possibly a sanitized, trimmed, and if needed anonymized version of the data) under [the Open Database License (ODbL) 1.0](https://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/1.0/), similar to how it was done with [the Stack Overflow Survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey).

How can I best announce this? There's a standard text for the license, but is there any standard text for the above?

The only thing I could think of is just writing something up myself:

> Note that your data will be shared as part of a (possibly sanitized and trimmed) data set to be published under the Open Database License 1.0 (https://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/1.0)

but, even though the above mostly relies on the well-thought-out license text, the little announcement was created just by myself, and I might be missing obvious caveats.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your statement.  For the sake of getting responses, I'd expand on "sanitized and trimmed".

Comment: Thx, I went with that option. I was asking here because I was curious what the 'right' option was, but in my specific case not too worried about getting into trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like your suggested statement would be fine. All you need to do here is tell people that you intend to publish the non-sensitive parts of their responses under the ODBL, then link to it and let 'em decide if they're comfortable with that. If you want more formal phrasing, try something like this:

> Responses to this survey will be stripped of personal or sensitive information, then published in aggregate as a dataset licensed under the [Open Database License (v1.0)](https://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/1.0).